# What is "competing advice"

Tags: usage

Frome this [Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/C-Integer-Types.html#C-Integer-Types):

> These guidelines sometimes give competing advice; common sense is advised.

I don't know what is *competing advice*. I also cannot figure out why *common sense* is advised and why *semicolon* is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These guidelines sometimes give **competing advice**; **common sense** is advised.

What it's saying is that those guidelines sometimes give you pieces of advice that might contradict each other in terms of what to do best in a certain situation. So, you have to use your [**common sense**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/common-sense) (your natural ability to make good judgments) to decide which piece of advice suits your particular situation better. That's really all it means.

As for the semicolon, this is actually one of the simplest [**rules of semicolon usage**](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html) in English:

> A semicolon is most commonly used to link in a single sentence two independent clauses that are closely related in thought.

Example:

> Some people write with a word processor; others write with a pen or pencil.